# Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO' -- Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, char

I'm beginner in Haskell. In this task i'm performing the split operation but i'm facing problem because of type mis match. I'm reading data from text file and the data is in table format. Ex. `1|2|Rahul|13.25.` In this format. Here `|` is delimiter so i want to split the data from the delimiter `|` and want to print 2nd column and 4th column data but i'm getting the error like this

```
  "Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO [Char]
      Actual type: [[Char]]
    In the return type of a call of `splitOn'"
```

Here is my code..

```
module Main where

import Data.List.Split

main = do
    list <- readFile("src/table.txt")
    putStrLn list
    splitOn "|" list
```

Any help regarding this will appreciate.. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you're trying to return a list from the `main` function, which has a type of `IO ()`.

What you probably want to do is print the result.

```
main = do
    list <- readFile("src/table.txt")
    putStrLn list
    print $ splitOn "|" list
```

Comment: ok thanks. it works properly but if i want to take 2nd column and 4th column values then how to fetch those values? i updated code like this..module Main where

import Data.List.Split

main = do
    list <- readFile("src/SalesDB.slc")
    putStrLn list
    let line = splitOn "|" list
    print $ line !! 1

Comment: @Rahul that sounds like a new question, rather than a comment, since this answered your question exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Not Haskell, but it looks like a typical awk task.

cat src/table.txt | awk -F'|' '{print $2, $4}'

Back to Haskell the best I could find is :

```
module Main where

import Data.List.Split(splitOn)
import Data.List (intercalate)

project :: [Int] -> [String] -> [String]
project indices l = foldl (\acc i -> acc ++ [l !! i]) [] indices

fromString :: String -> [[String]]
fromString = map (splitOn "|") . lines

toString :: [[String]] -> String
toString = unlines . map (intercalate "|")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn =<<
    return . toString . map (project [1, 3]) . fromString =<<
    readFile("table.txt")
```

If not reading from a file, but from stdin, the `interact` function could be useful.

Comment: What about `project indices l = [ l !! i | i <- indices ]` ?