# issue with sorting and addition

Tags: sorting, haskell, addition

i'm beginner in haskell. i wrote code in haskell to read a text file and print 2nd and 4th column but i dont know where to put sorting mechnism and 2nd column consists of digits so if digits are repeating then its values should be added and show the total for ex.

2|23.45

4|36.89

1|77.20

2|20.20

so output should be

1|77.20

2|43.65

4|36.89

my code is:

```
module Main where

import Data.List.Split(splitOn)
import Data.List (intercalate)

project :: [Int] -> [String] -> [String]
project indices l = foldl (\acc i -> acc ++ [l !! i]) [] indices

fromString :: String -> [[String]]
fromString = map (splitOn "|") . lines

toString :: [[String]] -> String
toString = unlines . map (intercalate "|")

main :: IO ()
main = do
putStrLn =<<
  return . toString . map (project [1, 3]) . fromString =<<
  readFile("table.txt")
```

help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should sort after `map`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn =<<
  return . toString . sort . map (project [1, 3]) . fromString =<<
  readFile("table.txt")
```

By the way, `return` and `=<<` can be simplified as follows:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  putStrLn . toString . sort . map (project [1, 3]) . fromString =<<
  readFile "table.txt"
```

This has still a couple of issues:

- it sorts the ID as strings, not the numbers (e.g. 11 comes before 4)
- it does not add the items with identical IDs

My suggestion would be:

1. convert the data into `[(Int,Double)]` first (have a look at `read` or -- if you want to sensibly handle malformed data -- `reads`).
2. sort the list.
3. apply a custom function to sum up the same-ID entries. This is a nice list-handling exercise for a beginner. Just fill the blanks below. Remember you can use recursion.

   ```
   sumSameId :: [(Int,Double)] -> [(Int,Double)]
   sumSameId [] = ???
   sumSameId [(i,d)] = ???
   sumSameId ((i1,d1):(i2,d2):rest) = if i1==i2 then ??? else ???
   ```

---

I have just realized that your code is not actually yours, but was taken verbatim from [an answer to a question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467031/couldnt-match-type-with-io-haskell). Honestly, it looks as you copied that code without making any effort to *understand* it, and are now trying to make it work using stackoverflow as a coding service. Of course, this may not be the case, yet it looks at it is. Just keep in mind that we usually are more keen to help people who show some effort.

Comment: He could also actually use `do` notation: `main = do s <- readFile "table.txt"; putStrLn . toString . sort . map (project [1, 3]) $ fromString s`.

Comment: According to your suggestion i put "sort" after "toString" but i'm getting error that "Not in scope 'sort'"

Comment: @Rahul You can import `sort` from `Data.List`.

Comment: @DavidYoung yes it works thanks but as i mentioned in the question. I have to do addition if two IDs are same.                           ex.                                                                    2|23.45

4|36.89

1|77.20

2|20.20                                                                      and it should print like this...

1|77.20

2|43.65

4|36.89                                                                                          it like same numbers are there in left side then its right side value should be add up and show the total..